# How to use Kwallet as default keyring

Tags: kde, gnome-keyring, plasma5, kwallet, keychain

I am using KDE desktop (plasma 5 ) environment with opensuse leap 42.1.

Many programs in my system use native keychain to store password like (JetBrain products). But when saving the password, I notice that the default keychain for my system is genom-keyring. How to configure my system to use KWallet as default keychain. I have uninstall genom-keyring with all its dependencies and now the system does not recognize any default keychain. How can I make Kwallet the default keychain?

Another question how can I avoid typing the paraphrase every time I sign in my account (to open the wallet)

Thank you very much

Comment: Installing `gnome-keyring` and then making the changes described at https://www.linuxsecrets.com/archlinux-wiki/wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDM.html#KDM_and_Gnome-keyring to the file `/etc/pam.d/sddm` (not `kdm` as in the outdated Wiki entry) helped avoiding typing the passphrase on every login (although I still have to do it occasionally, this seems like a bug to me)

Comment: see the archwiki [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE_Wallet)